# ValidatorEnable does not work through JQuery Code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have to enable disable the `Required Field Validator` from Client side. I am writing the following code.

```
document.getElementById('ctl00_Container_ucControl_RequiredFieldValControlName');
ValidatorEnable(Object, false);
```

I tried using JQuery. I can get the object but in this way `ValidatorEnable` is not working.

I don't want to write the complete ID using JQuery.

Your comments

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way :

```
ValidatorEnable($([id$='RequiredFieldValControlName'])[0],false)
```

Comment: but the client id is `ctl00_Container_ucControl_RequiredFieldValControlName`

Comment: This will work $([id$='RequiredFieldValControlName']) this mean ClientId end with 'RequiredFieldValControlName' this will avoid you to put the full generated id!

Comment: You can also try it this way if you prefere : ValidatorEnable($('#ctl00_Container_ucControl_RequiredFieldValControlName')[0],false)

Comment: **TypeError: val.style is undefined** ` 

val.style.visibility = val.isvalid ? "hidden" : "visible";`

Comment: I don't want to write the complete id.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21341/discussion-between-anass-and-ytftyffty)

Comment: Use full name like ValidatorEnable($('#<%=RequiredFieldValControlName.ClientID%>')[0],false)